# how to merge two dictionaries with different keys that are inside same list?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

```
[
    {"id": "cef8bab0-8482-4086-bc8f-29bf229f13f6"},
    {
        "createdAt": "2018-12-18T16:09:57.098Z",
        "notes": "Candidate initial submission.",
        "createdBy": "Steven Klinger",
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2018-12-18T23:14:09.415Z",
        "notes": "The Candidate Status has now been updated from <strong>CV Submitted</strong> and <strong>Feedback Pending</strong> to <strong>Client CV Review</strong> and <strong>Feedback Awaiting</strong>",
        "createdBy": "Matt",
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2019-01-22T16:04:46.958Z",
        "notes": "The Candidate Status has now been updated from <strong>Client CV Review</strong> and <strong>Feedback Awaiting</strong> to <strong>Client CV Review</strong> and <strong>Position on Hold</strong>",
        "createdBy": "Matt",
    },
]
```

i have this list.  inside i have two dictionaries. i want to merge both into a single dictionary inside the list.

Comment: Your data is a list that contains four different dictionaries. Please show us the desired end result, too.

Comment: @AKX i need a normalised data. also this is just one row. i have 53000 such rows containing lists of dicitionaries.  some has more dictionaries nested, may be 21 such dictionaries.

Comment: Give us an example of what you'd want out of _this_ row, then?

Comment: @AKX please check, i have uploaded an image

Comment: I understand, but you still haven't told us what you'd want as the output from the example row with 4 dicts.

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to merge the `id` dict into each dict with the other structure, this works:

```
id_dict = [d for d in l if 'id' in d][0]
merge = [ {**d, **id_dict} for d in l if 'id' not in d]
```

Comment: You don't need the list roundtrip: `dict(d, **id_dict)` will happily merge the two dicts (and `{**d, **id_dict}` on recent Pythons too).

Comment: @AamerAshfaque please provide more detail. I set `l = [ {"id"....` (the list you give); followed by this code; and `merge` is the expected result. What is failing for you?

Comment: @Joshua Fox ,there are 53000 rows, each has such ls

Comment: Are you saying that there is a list of 53000 rows, where each row resembles the list you put here? In that case, show a list of 2 rows (so that there is more than one row). In general, you should provide a minimal  example illustrating your point. In this case, an example of  input and also expected output.

Comment: @Joshua Fox ,there are such lists in each row. total rows are 53000.

Comment: @Joshua Fox , see i just added the image . how it is

Comment: Please use text, not images. That image is not of Python code--is this a text file that you need to process? If so, your first step is the parse each line to extract the Python list-of-dictionaries